# Laptop restarting with a blue screen

Tags: laptop, motherboard

Hi I'm not good in hardware side. I have a Toshiba Satellite L510 Laptop with Core 2 duo Processor. Recently it was showing some issue. While I was using suddenly it appears blue screen and showed that machine was memory dumping... then it restarted.. This happened for so many times.. Now I cannot even switch on it. Issue happening repeatedly. Some one told me that problem is with motherboard and ask me to replace.. 
Anyone has experienced this ?? Does anyone know any solution to this.. Please help me...

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Blue Screen of Death !!! Probably check the hard disk fro errors .

Comment: Check hard disk, memory, laptop temperature  and try to post the problem in Toshiba's forum maybe they can give you a better answer.

Comment: thnx .. you mean from BIOS screen? I think I checked.. Anyway.. let me try it.. I'll let you know.. Thanx again

Comment: Thanx Andres,... Ok I'll post this in Toshiba forum as well..

Comment: What's the STOP code in the bluescreen?

Comment: its not same in each time.. its shows different codes.. It says memory dumping, then it count 1-100. then its rebooting..

Comment: Try booting off of an Ubuntu live CD.  If you can do that, then it's a software-related issue with your Windows install for sure.  If not, then you know it's something to do with hardware.  If you can't get consistent, reproducible behavior, but just random failures, no choice really but to swap components with known working ones until it stops.

Comment: Thank you ultrasawblade.. Ok I'll try with a ubantu CD. I havent tried it yet.. actually its a good point to check. Thanx again